# How can I allow *any* user to read files from `/sys/kernel/debug/...`?

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

How can I allow *any* user to read files from `/sys/kernel/debug/...`? While creating a `debugfs` file, I realized that only `root` on my `ubuntu` machine can access the `debugfs` files in `/sys/kernel/debug/...`, even for only reading. Now while googling, I came across this article on [lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/429321/) which talks about permissions on `debugfs`. Finally, are there any other distributions which allow `any` user to read from `/sys/kernel/debug/test/TestFile` where `testFile` is a file created through `debugfs` API? I have checked on Debian and Ubuntu machines but I cannot access `/sys/kernel/debug` except when logged in as root.

Comment: `sudo chmod a+rx /sys/kernel/debug`. This grants non-root access to debugfs until reboot (more precise, until debugfs will be unmounted and mounted again).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo vi /etc/init/mounted-debugfs.conf
```

and change

```
script
    chmod 0700 "${MOUNTPOINT}" || true
end script
```

to

```
script
    chmod 0755 "${MOUNTPOINT}" || true
end script
```